# Reversing SVG text on bottom of a radial?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

http://jsfiddle.net/ttr85xuj/

Text past a certain degree should be mirrored...I'm positive it's a translate attribute, but honestly I think I may have to redo the way I'm appending the text & textPath, maybe the svg:path before it. When I apply `translate` it doesn't seem to be relative to anything.

```
    path.append("text")
        .style("font-size", "15px")
        .attr("dy", function(d) {
            return 20 - (d.value / 2)
                // return (d.value * 15) - (d.value * 2);
        })
        .attr('transform', function(d) {
            var angle = (d.x + d.dx / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
            if (Math.floor(angle) == 119) {
                return ""
            } else {
                return ""
            }
            // return 'scale(-1 1)'
        })
        .append("textPath")
        .attr("textLength", function(d, i) {
            return 120 - i * 4;
        })
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
            // debugger;
            return "#" + d.name + i;
            // return "#" + (i);
        })
        .attr("startOffset", function(d, i) {
            return 3 / 29;
        })
        .attr("dy", "-1em")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.name;
        })
```

Any help would be appreciated. Not sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: If you want the text to run in the opposite direction, the path has to run in the opposite direction.  There isn't a transform that you can do to the textPath afterwards to achieve that effect.

Comment: Just trying to help but would an if/then past a certain angle, with a 180 degree transform, not do the trick?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672569/d3-js-upside-down-path-text